# Laravel 4: Eloquent relationship get all data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 relationship data table; users table and memberdetails table.

Users.php

```
class Users extends Eloquent{

    public function memberdetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Memberdetails','user_id');
    }
}
```

Memberdetails.php

```
class Memberdetails extends Eloquent{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Users','user_id');
    }
}
```

When I try to retrieve data, with `$data = User::find($id);` I only get data from users table.

Example of my blade form:

```
{{-- User's Name, stored on user table --}}
{{ Form::text('name',null, array('id'=>'name','class'=>'form-control','required')) }}

{{-- User's address, stored on member table --}}
{{ Form::text('address',null, array('id'=>'address','class'=>'form-control','required')) }}
```

When I visit, `localhost/user/2/edit/`, the name field is populated, but address field is empty. How can I retrieve data from both tables and put into a form for editing?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need that 'user_id' param

Answer (score 22):

You could use eager loading.

```
$user = User::with('memberdetails')->find($id);
```

Using this, you will automatically get the memberdetails when retrieving the user. Then you can use `$user->memberdetails`

Using eager loading, you do only one query to the DB so it should be the preferred way. If you dont use the `with('memberdetails')`, you will perform a second query when accessing the memberdetails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can i put the memberdetails data into the form? The form only appear data with user table.

Comment: $user->memberdetails->id and so on? Your user has only one memberdetails so you can use it directly.

Comment: Because I am working with blade form. Once I pass data it, it automatically populate the data into the form based on form name. So, now only user table is populated into the form.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the user instance, access the relationship, then you can access the other class properties

```
$user = User::find($id);
$userData = $user->memberdetails;
```

Comment: This doesn't take advantage of Eloquent's eager loading.